# why i'm NOT getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

From my understanding to two dimensional arrays in Java i know that it can be initialized like this:

```
int a[][] = new int[3][1];
```

**3->represents the row**

**1->represents the col**

as in the pic:

[image]

My question is why when i use this:

```
    int a[][] = new int[3][1]; 
    a[4] =new int[]{1,2,3,3,4};
    System.out.print(a[4][4]);
```

it gives:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: which is the right behavior where a[4] is out of index because of the size which is 3.

But using this won't give any Exception:

```
        int a[][] = new int[3][1]; 
        a[1] = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4};
        a[2] = new int[]{4,5};
        System.out.print(a[1][4]);
```

even tho a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUySo.png)[4] does exist in the initialization but it is out of index as the size of col is equal to 1.

Any ideas!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign

```
a[1] = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4};
```

`a[1]` now refers to an int array of 5 elements, so `a[1][4]` is valid. It doesn't matter than originally `a[1]` referred to an int array of 1 element, since after the assignment, `a[1]` refers to a new array.

You should remember that a 2-D array is actually an array of arrays (i.e. array whose element type is an array). Therefore you can assign a new inner array to any index of the outer array.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a **two dimensional** array is actually an `Array of Arrays`.

So, when you do,

```
int a[][] = new int[3][1];
```

It translates to,

```
a[0] = new int[1];
a[1] = new int[1];
a[2] = new int[1];
```

Not, that `a` as an array has only **one** dimension. But each element in it can hold another array **of any length but int type**.

So, when you do,

```
a[1] = new int[5];
```

It's still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a[1] as "new" which will override the array size count